# Can we dynamically add data in the google docs in php or laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to show the data on the web page in the google docs. Means I have a web page, this page has some data now I want to show this data on the google docs.

Comment: Google has an API for creating documents and storing them on Drive

Comment: Can you share a link? @ka_lin

Comment: I want to change on the same sheet.

Comment: I have searched already and google provide API for the google sheet but not for the google docs.

Comment: Google REST API - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads